# Launch using dedicated graphics card option disappeared

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-gnome

I had that menu option on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop with an Nvidia GPU, and it disappeared. It existed before which makes this really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I enabled secure boot, I'm not sure how and when it was disabled on this computer, but I saw it disabled a few days ago and I enabled it, it seems that the MOK was removed from the firmware, and I had to re-enroll it, and that's why the menu item disappeared, the Nvidia driver was not available.
I didn't see an error message on boot, strangely enough.

Comment: This is confusing. First you say you enabled secure boot, bad for Ubuntu. What message on boot did you expect. Where was this menu option? Your question needs some details.

Comment: Faliure in loading nvidia drivers, for instance.